# Prevent Material3 TimeInput from always requiring focus

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

I'm implementing a custom dialog that combines Material3's `DatePicker` and `TimeInput` into one `Dialog` to allow a user to select a start date and time in one action. It looks good but `TimeInput` *always* has focus in either the hours or minutes input box, and there doesn't seem to be any way to end this focus. I haven't seen anything in any documentation about this focus behavior. This almost seems like a bug. Am I missing some way to prevent this?

This is the behavior I see when the dialog is opened. The Hour box is selected and keyboard automatically opens. Tapping outside the `TimePicker` does not affect focus. Closing keyboard does not even clear focus.

[image]

This is the code for my custom `DateTimeDialog`

```
@Suppress("LongParameterList")
@Composable
fun DateTimeDialog(
    datePickerState: DatePickerState,
    timeInputState: TimePickerState,
    pickerType: CalendarPickerType,
    title: @Composable () -> Unit = { DefaultTitle() },
    headline: @Composable () -> Unit = { DefaultHeadline(state = datePickerState) },
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    onConfirmRequest: (DateTimeData) -> Unit,
    dismissButtonText: String = stringResource(id = R.string.cancel),
    confirmButtonText: String = stringResource(id = R.string.save)
) {
    Dialog(onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    Theme.colors.backgroundPrimary,
                    RoundedCornerShape(Theme.spacing.spacing150)
                ),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            DatePicker(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(Theme.spacing.spacing150)),
                title = title,
                state = datePickerState,
                headline = headline,
                dateValidator = { calendarValidator(pickerType, it) },
                showModeToggle = false,
                colors = datePickerColors()
            )

            TimeInput(
                state = timeInputState,
                colors = timePickerColors()
            )

            BottomButtons(
                confirmButtonEnabled = datePickerState.selectedDateMillis != null,
                onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
                onConfirmRequest = {
                    datePickerState.selectedDateMillis?.let {
                        onConfirmRequest(
                            DateTimeData(
                                dateEpochMilli = it,
                                timeHour = timeInputState.hour,
                                timeMinute = timeInputState.minute
                            )
                        )
                    }
                },
                dismissButtonText = dismissButtonText,
                confirmButtonText = confirmButtonText
            )
        }
    }
}
```